# my stripe secret key does not want to load from an .env file

Tags: react-native, npm, stripe-payments, .env

I am working on a project using for frontend: react native, backend: nodejs and mysql, and for taking some payments i am using stripe and with that i am having big problems. In react native to initialize the stripe object i have to write **const stipe = new Stripe(secret key);** but i cannot write my secret key as plaintext in there so i am using .env right now and i am trying to get the key like:

`const stripe = new Stripe(Config.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);`

i have to try and get the key again when creating a customer i have to use:

`Authorization: Config.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY`

but i get this error message:

Object {
"message": "Invalid API Key provided: undefined",
"type": "invalid_request_error",
}

i already tried it with some packages that i installed with npm like

`process.env`
`Config.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY`
`DotEnv.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY`

can please someone help me out

Comment: Where is your .env file located in your file structure? Are you able to access any other settings from your .env file?

Comment: It is in the root folder and i don't have any other settings than the STRIPE_SECRET_KEY